# Couldn't Authorization Server be busy, when million of users exists on Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I have used Microservice Architecture in an Enterprise Application. There are more microservices in my architecture using Spring Boot. I have made a my own Microservice as Authorization service using Keycloak. Here I'm doing Authentication in every Microservice calling to Authorization Service & get JWT Token. on every endpoint, call to Authorization service to validate JWT Token & give permission. when this Application is used by Millions of Users, couldn't Authorization Server be Busy. How to Handle Load here. I think, making more instances of Authorization Service and Balance Load is not Good Practise to the Authorization Server.

give me a Solution good for industrial Application

Answer (score 0):

New JWTs should not be fetched for each request: a given OAuth2 client should use the same access-token until it expires.

JWT are signed and can be validated by clients and resource-servers without the help of the authorization-server (only a single call at startup to fetch signing public key is required).

So no, authorization-server should not be specially stressed.

Comment: There is an Internal Authorization Server in our Organization. in Here, all you above mentioned scenarios handle. I have used endpoints exposed by the Organization's Authorization server in my own authorization server(Microservice). When A user login, get a Jwt token & send it until it expired on Headers in all requests.  on every request, I called my own Authorization server's(Microservice) validate endpoint. that calls to Internal Authorization Server. So my own Authorization Server can be stressed. I don't know secret key. they are all handled in Internal Authorization Server.

Comment: Please give me help

Comment: It seems you have as little notions of OAuth2 mechanism as English. I just don't understand your comment and suspect you don't know how Oauth2 requests are authorized: every request to a secured resource should have an authorization header with a valid access-token, the resource-server being a micro-service does not change a thing. Just configure your client(s) to send requests with tokens (and renew it only when necessary).